# Custom header view overlapped by UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

In interface builder I have a header view above my UITableView, however in the simulator it is missing, and the Table View seems to be over it since it takes up most of the screen.  Any reason for this?  Work around?

**Interface Builder**

[image]

**Simulator**

[image]

Comment: How many section is in your tableview?

Comment: Simply just code: [self.view addSubview:headerView]; this will work or you could go for - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section; and create your header(UIView) in that.

Answer (score 0):

In your case:

From your interface builder image I can see that table view is subview of view and you header view is also subview of tableview. It happening because tableview is hiding the header view. if you add the header view as subview of tableview then it would appear. But adding subview will not solve your problem because when you will scroll the tableview the subview will be gone.

For solving your problem as I can see that you have a navigation bar in your table view you can add the header view as subview of `UINavigationBar`.

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:headerView];
```

**Good Practise:**

Set the header view for section. Then you don't need to set any custom view at the top of your tableview. Try this:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    //Customize the view according to our requirment
    return aView;
}
```

Also implement this:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 44.f; // Make this height as you need. Or else you may not see the full view.
}
```

Btw you can create a subclass of `UITableViewController` instead of `UIViewController`.
Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Deselect Extend Edges / Under Top Bars

[image]